# preg_replace() not working on array

Tags: php, arrays, regex

I have the following code:

```
$pattern_dig_answer = array(); // Identify patterns to replace and their replacements
$pattern_dig_answer[0] = "/(.*)IN(\s+)A(.*)/";
$replacement_dig_answer = array();
$replacement_dig_answer[0] = "<span style='color:red;'>$1IN$2A$3</span>";
```

The first entry for the pattern_dig_answer array is some regex for the pattern I'm looking to match. The first entry for the replacement_dig_answer is what I am looking to replace what the regex finds with.

I then execute a dig like so:

```
$dig_answer = exec("dig {$_SESSION['domain']} $digrecords[2] $digops[0] $digops[1] $digops[2] $digops[3]", $dig_answer_raw);
```

Which, as you may guess, executes a dig command with session variables captured from user input and then saves the output to $dig_answer_raw.

What I now do is clean up the dig with the following:

```
$dig_answer_out = preg_grep('/IN/', $dig_answer_raw);
```

And then I echo the results:

```
echo implode("\n", $dig_answer_out);
```

This all works fine up until this point. It's only when I go to do the following that I get stuck:

```
echo preg_replace($pattern_dig_answer, $replacement_dig_answer, $dig_answer_out);
```

Now, from the investigating I've done, this should work. The documentation for preg_replace clearly says that it can search either in a normal string or via an array with string entries (which I'm assuming I have). What makes me think that I might not is as soon as I change the dig command to this:

```
$dig_answer = shell_exec("dig {$_SESSION['domain']} $digrecords[2] $digops[0] $digops[1] $digops[2] $digops[3]");
```

It works like a charm, however negates all the output cleaning that preg_grep did previously even after changing around all the variables.

Is there something painfully obvious that I'm missing here?

EDIT: To try and simplify my question, when my dig command is changed from exec(), which saves the output to an array, to shell_exec, which saves the output to a string, then preg_replace works. It doesn't seem to want to work in an array and I'm not sure why...

Comment: "*however negates all the output cleaning that preg_grep did previously even after changing around all the variables.*" — What do you mean by that?

Comment: As in when I replace my dig command with:

`$dig_answer = shell_exec("dig {$_SESSION['domain']} $digrecords[2] $digops[0] $digops[1] $digops[2] $digops[3]");`

And then:

`echo preg_replace($pattern_dig_answer, $replacement_dig_answer, $dig_answer_out);`

It works.

Comment: you're first 'pattern_dig_answer' is missing a dollar sign

Comment: @chiliNUT A failure of my copy/paste skills I'm afraid. Thanks for pointing that out though. I'll patch that up now.

Comment: @id0827502: I'm not sure what you're asking then. Can you edit the question to include *just* the part that is not working? I think that'd help clarify what you're asking.

Comment: var_dump() your array and see if what values your getting. Also echo out when you do value changes to see if it's working right. That way you can see whats going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've split your code so it's tricky to tell what you're running. I think this is it, reconstructed from all of the parts as follows:

```
<?php
$pattern_dig_answer = array(); // Identify patterns to replace and their replacements
$pattern_dig_answer[0] = "/(.*)IN(\s+)A(.*)/";
$replacement_dig_answer = array();
$replacement_dig_answer[0] = "<span style='color:red;'>$1IN$2A$3</span>";

$dig_answer = exec("dig google.com", $dig_answer_raw);
$dig_answer_out = preg_grep('/IN/', $dig_answer_raw);
echo implode("\n", $dig_answer_out);
echo preg_replace($pattern_dig_answer, $replacement_dig_answer, $dig_answer_out);
```

When I run this over a CLI (PHP 5.5.11) I get a warning: `PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion` on the line where you're calling `echo preg_replace(...);`.

You're (implicitly) converting the array that is returned by `preg_replace()` to a string with `echo`. Since you're passing in an `array()` for `preg_replace` for both parameters, you're getting back an `array` (as you assumed). The best way to dump those to view what is inside is with [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/var_dump). If you want to print it in a different way you could use a `foreach` loop and print that element.

```
<?php
$pattern_dig_answer = array(); // Identify patterns to replace and their replacements
$pattern_dig_answer[0] = "/(.*)IN(\s+)A(.*)/";
$replacement_dig_answer = array();
$replacement_dig_answer[0] = "<span style='color:red;'>$1IN$2A$3</span>";

$dig_answer = exec("dig google.com", $dig_answer_raw);
$dig_answer_out = preg_grep('/IN/', $dig_answer_raw);
implode("\n", $dig_answer_out);
$total_output = preg_replace($pattern_dig_answer, $replacement_dig_answer, $dig_answer_out);
foreach ($total_output as $output) {
    echo $output."<br />\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining this. Is this somewhat of a rule of thumb? If it goes in a string, it needs to come out a string? Same goes for arrays. I need to do more homework on arrays...any suggestions?

Comment: Not really, rules of thumb are kinda weird with PHP, there aren't any. For the arrays, in terms of other languages they're not like an array in C or Java or a list in Python; in terms of Python they're closer to being halfway between a list and a dict, and can't *necessarily* be iterated by index. The PHP [array](http://au2.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) documentation is pretty clear on a lot of the weirder parts to arrays as well.

Comment: A good recommendation is to check the PHP site documentation to see what each argument is and how it gets returned. Sometimes the errors are the return values, sometimes they're not. Sometimes the return value is returned, sometimes you have to give it the variable you want it to fill as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I reconstructed the script based on your original post:

```
<?php

$dig_answer = exec("dig www.google.com.au", $dig_answer_raw);

$dig_answer_out = preg_grep('/IN/', $dig_answer_raw);

$pattern_dig_answer = array(); // Identify patterns to replace and their replacements
$pattern_dig_answer[0] = "/(.*)IN(\s+)A(.*)/";
$replacement_dig_answer = array();
$replacement_dig_answer[0] = "<span style='color:red;'>$1IN$2A$3</span>";

$x = preg_replace($pattern_dig_answer, $replacement_dig_answer, $dig_answer_out);
print_r($x);
```

The output from this script looks like it is working for me:

```
Array
(
   [8] => <span style='color:red;'>;www.google.com.au.      IN  A</span>
   [11] => <span style='color:red;'>www.google.com.au.  125 IN  A   203.219.219.163</span>
   ...
)
```

Am I missing something? For reference, this is the output of `php -v` for me.

> PHP 5.4.24 (cli) (built: Jan 19 2014 21:32:15)

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed that this line may not produce what you are expecting:

`echo preg_replace($pattern_dig_answer, $replacement_dig_answer, $dig_answer_out);`

In this instance, `preg_replace()` will return an array as you have passed an array as the first and second arguments. Try this instead:

`$foo = preg_replace($pattern_dig_answer, $replacement_dig_answer, $dig_answer_out);
var_dump($foo);`